# how to define number of links shown in sfDoctrine Pager

Tags: symfony1

I searched stackoverflow for a way to set the number of links returned by the sfDoctrine Pager. I ended up looking through the code to find the function declaration for getLinks. That function takes one parameter that is defaulted to 5. You can change it, getLinks(10). Does anyone know of a resource that shows all the available options for sfDoctrine Pager class. I am using Symfony 1.4

Comment: How about the [api docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfDoctrinePager)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [sfPager documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfPager).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the constructor for [sfDoctrinePager](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfPager#method___construct) you will notice that the second parameter if the maximum number of items per page ... so

```
$this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager('modelclass',10);
```

where 10 is the maximum number of items per page.

The [API docs are here](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/) ... and specifically the [sfDoctrinPager docs are here](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfDoctrinePager)